# REGEXP_COUNT FIND > [ ] < OCCURRENSE IN ORACLE

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a string which is: 'ShippingInstructions.Phone[2].type.field[5].name' like:

```
SELECT 'ShippingInstructions.Phone[2].type.field[5].name' FROM DUAL;
```

I want to find how many [...] occurreses I have into mentioned string.

The response must to be 2.

Mine idea is:
each pair of [...] counts per 1.

I used the REGEXP_COUNT expression but it doesn't work because **[]** uses like a list of possibilities.

How can I find the **strict** occurrenses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This?

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'ShippingInstructions.Phone[2].type.field[52].name' from dual)
  3  select regexp_count(col, '\[\d+\]') result
  4  from test;

    RESULT
----------
         2

SQL>
```

Comment: Hello, It works, but could you append one little thing?
It works better with regexp_count(col, '\[*.\]'), because maybe I can put two digits.
The post no prints \ character... I think you can understand me

Thanks

Comment: If these are digits, then perhaps you'd want to consider `\d+` (modified in answer's code).

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the brackets using `\` and use:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_COUNT( value, '\[\d+\]' ) AS num_brackets,
       value
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT 'ShippingInstructions.Phone[2].type.field[5].name' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a.b[1].c[2].d[3].e[4].f[5].g[6].h[7].i[8].j[9].k[10].name' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | NUM_BRACKETS | VALUE |
> | --- | --- |
> | 2 | ShippingInstructions.Phone[2].type.field[5].name |
> | 10 | a.b[1].c[2].d[3].e[4].f[5].g[6].h[7].i[8].j[9].k[10].name |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e3fb7c8f2b023ab66f35d1b8f3e2de11)*

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_COUNT(col, '\[[^][]+]')
```

The `\[[^][]+]` will match any non-empty `[...]` substrings. If they can be empty, like `[]`, use `\[[^][]*]` regex.

The `[^][]` part matches any char but a `]` and `[` chars.

*Details*

- `\[` - a `[` char, escaped since the `[` is a special regex metacharacter
- `[^][]+` - a negated (`^` after `[` expresses negation) bracket expression that matches any chars other than `]` and `[` (note the `]` is not escaped as it is the first char in the bracket expression)
- `]` - a `]` char (it is not special when outside a bracket expression, hence unescaped).